# How to make MySQL's WEEK() and YEARWEEK() function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I still maintain an application that I built years and years ago which has a calendar type overview of data, organized by week.

In my code, there are references to the `YEARWEEK()` and `WEEK()` functions in MySQL.

For some reason, I'll get an email near the beginning of every year stating that the calendar links are not working correctly. (The calendar links are generated based on the week number of that year.)

In a nut shell, I end up passing in the `mode` parameter to the `WEEK()` and `YEARWEEK()` functions. So one year I'll pass in 1 as the second parameter, and the next year, I'll pass in 0. And basically, every year I'm forced to make this change programmatically to fix the problem, going back between 1 and 0.

I'm forced to do this because all the weeks will be offset by 1 when the calendar is not functioning correctly. So I might want to click on week 10, but I'm getting data for week 11.

Unless someone has specifically come across this problem, I don't know if it will be that easy for someone to come up with a good answer for me.

Comment: SO why do you have to make this change?

Comment: [The manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) provides the reason. So all you have to do is code something to work out where Jan 1 falls in the first week of the year

Comment: Do you know the business rules of how weeks are counted for your software?

Comment: Sounds to me like the link generation OR the code interpreting them is broken by design -- the mode should be a fixed setting, because otherwise a link generated for a given day around 1.1.xxxx may change depending on the time it is generated, or it is broken because the interpretation changed

Comment: If you guys check out my comment to the answer below, what I am saying is I have a calendar view which needs to be able to look at data from the past 10 years. So some years the calendar of weeks works fine, whereas other years don't. It's almost like I need to switch the mode depending on what year I'm looking at.

Comment: Maybe if you showed the code generating the link, and the code taking it apart could help to shed some light on the problem

Answer (score 1):

Since you're referring to *mode* 0 and 1, I suspect you might not be aware there are actually eight *modes*. Without knowing the business rules for your website I can't tell which one you need, but the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) is pretty explicit.

You must ask yourself three questions about your business rules:

- Are weeks starting on a Sunday or Monday?

  - *Modes* (0,2,4,6) are for weeks starting on a Sunday
  - *Modes* (1,3,5,7) are for weeks starting on a Monday
- Are there 53 or 54 weeks identifiers in a year?

  - *Modes* (0,1,4,5) are for 54 weeks year format
  - *Modes* (2,3,6,7) are for 53 weeks year format
- Is the first week based on the first Sunday/Monday or the one with most weekdays in year?

  - *Modes* (0,2,5,7) is for the year containing the first day of the week
  - *Modes* (1,3,4,6) is for the year containing more than half of weekdays of the week

N.B. Although not documented for `YEARWEEK()`, the `WEEK()` modes are the same

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm guessing the reason my application breaks is because the calendar overview should be able to look at data for any week from the past 10 years. So my code works for certain years when the criteria you mentioned is met for the mode I am using, and in other years when it doesn't meet the above criteria, the code will not work for those years.

Comment: @Justin, will you provide a specific example of a date that gives the expected outcome, and a date that doesn't (with what you expect instead)? 

My intention is to prove that, 10 years ago or 200 years ago, you can have your way.